# Victor airways that have a floor above 1200 ft AGL

Tags: airspace, class-e-airspace, airways, class-g-airspace

Chapter 5, section 3 of the AIM says that victor airways are "designated from 1200 ft above the surface (*or in some instances higher) up to but not including 18,000 ft MSL."

What are the instances of victor airways having a floor higher than 1200 ft AGL? Is it just when class G airspace extends higher than 1200 ft AGL?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Victor airway’s bottoms are higher than 1,200ft when there is class G airspace that prevents the class E from existing there.

Comment: Is there a missing "only" in this sentence, or are you merely confirming the information in the question?

Comment: I was more directly answering the question. There may be other situations but I am not knowledgeable on that.